# meteor 0.9 upgrade and iron-router template error

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm upgrading our meteor app to 0.9 and got this error:

```
Couldn't find a template named "defaultLayout" or "defaultLayout". Are you sure you defined it?
```

I use the following commands to add iron router packages:

```
meteor add iron:core
meteor add iron:router
meteor add iron:layout
meteor add iron:dynamic-template
```

Our configure code is in iron-router.js:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'defaultLayout'
})
```

Directory tree looks like this:

```
client/helpers/iron-router.js
client/views/layout/default.html.jade
```

I also tried adding only iron:router package. Got same error. Do I need to move Router.configure somewhere else?

Comment: and that template is defined somewhere? Also, where is `iron-router.js` in your project directory tree?

Comment: updated with directory tree. No problem with 0.8.3.

Comment: can you show us the 'defaultLayout' template definition?

Comment: I need to upgrade jade package to new meteor packaging system. But once I do that, app doesn't start with error in meteor-tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I need to upgrade jade package to new meteor packaging system. Once I do that, the error goes away. The error is caused by incompatibility of old jade package with new iron:router package.